# Javascript Algolia - How to initiate a new search with an empty search string?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, algolia

I have a piece of functionality in my Angular app in which I have some searchable items that exist within my Algolia database. The thing is...they aren't searchable by any string. They are only searchable via facets.

The problem is that when I run my initial .search() function with an empty string + my search filters/facets, I get a list returned and everything is all fine and dandy. HOWEVER, when I go to run the function again to refresh the list, it just comes back with the same results and actually never fires a new request, unless I change one of the filters/facets.

Is there any way to force a search query any time I want, without having to specify a "new" search criteria?

Here is my search function:

```
searchForAuditions() {

    // Setup the filters/options
    let options = {
      highlightPreTag: '<span class="highlighted">',
      highlightPostTag: '</span>',
      hitsPerPage: 10,
    };

    // Add clause to make sure "is_deleted" is false
    let isDeleted = ` is_deleted: "false"`;

    let facets = `${isDeleted}`;

    // Replace all trailing spaces and split it into an array
    let facetWords = facets.replace(/\s+$/, '').split(" ");

    // Remove trailing "AND"
    if((facetWords[facetWords.length - 1] === "AND") || (facetWords[facetWords.length - 1] === "OR")) {
      facetWords.splice(-1, 1);
      facets = facetWords.join(' ');
    }

    if(facets) {
      options['filters'] = facets;
    }

    this.auditionsIndex.search('', options).then(result => {
      this.results = result.hits;
    })
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the algolia JavaScript client documentation,

> To avoid performing the same API calls twice search results will be stored in a cache that will be tied to your JavaScript client and index objects. **Whenever a call for a specific query (and filters) is made, we store the results in a local cache. If you ever call the exact same query again, we read the results from the cache instead of doing an API call.**
>
> This is particularly useful when your users are deleting characters
>   from their current query, to avoid useless API calls. Because it is
>   stored as a simple JavaScript object in memory, the cache is
>   automatically reset whenever you reload the page.

To resolve this you should use

`index.clearCache()` or `client.clearCache()`

Read more about the inbuilt cache system here.
https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-javascript#cache

Comment: What an elegant solution. I figured something like this was the case, but I couldn't find it in the documentation. Thanks for helping me out :D

Comment: Hey one quick thing on this: I'm noticing that when I run my clearCache function right before the search, when the results reload, it always takes two reloads to get the update, as if the reload is a "reload behind", if that makes sense. Every time I run the search function, it gives me old results that should have showed up the reload before. Any thoughts?